# Using a match to create a new column for a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes on which to perform an lapply function. The goal is to add a new column, `symbol`, to each dataframe by matching by rownames to another reference dataframe. This works great in a non-lapply form:

```
df1$symbol <- dds$symbol[ match(rownames(df1), rownames(dds)) ]
```

But fails in lapply with multiple syntax attempts. The closest I seem to get is:

```
result_list <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
lapply(result_list, function(x) {
  x$symbol <- dds$symbol[ match(rownames(x), rownames(dds)) ]
})

[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

Warning messages:
1: In x$symbol <- mcols(dds)$symbol[match(rownames(x), rownames(dds))] :
  Coercing LHS to a list
2: In x$symbol <- mcols(dds)$symbol[match(rownames(x), rownames(dds))] :
  Coercing LHS to a list
3: In x$symbol <- mcols(dds)$symbol[match(rownames(x), rownames(dds))] :
  Coercing LHS to a list
```

Or alternately:

```
lapply(result_list, function(x) {
  x[["symbol"]] <- dds$symbol[ match(rownames(x), rownames(dds)) ]
})
Error in x[["symbol"]] <- dds$symbol[ match(rownames(x), rownames(dds)) ] :
  replacement has length zero

lapply(result_list, function(x) {
  x[["symbol"]] <- dds[["symbol"]][ match(rownames(x), rownames(dds)) ]
})
Error in x[["symbol"]] <- dds[["symbol"]][ match(rownames(x), rownames(dds)) ] :
  replacement has length zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get the values of the 'string' in a list.  `mget` returns the 'data.frame's from the based on the identifiers as strings

```
lst1 <- mget(result_list)
```

and then loop through the 'lst1'

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) {
   x$symbol <- dds$symbol[ match(rownames(x), rownames(dds)) ]
   x
   })
```